# git: How to merge an older state if a newer state has already been merged?

Tags: git, git-merge, branching-and-merging

We had a branch (let's say branch `A`) with some modifications we wanted to merge to `master`, and some modifications we didn't want to merge yet, but wanted to keep for later use. We didn't rebase/split the commits, and simply went for a manual modification of the code.

So we created a new branch (branch `B`) from branch `A`, to save the entire code in the current state, including the modifications we wanted to merge later. In the existing branch (branch `A`), we manually modify the code to remove the parts we didn't want to merge for now.

Then we merged branch `A` to master. The problem is, if we now try to merge branch `B`, git merge says everything is up-to-date. I guess this is because there is no difference specifically in `B` as compared to the common ancestor of `B` and `master` (ie, branch `A` before removal of parts of the code, which is identical to branch `B`). For instance, `git diff master...B` show no diff. But there exist actual differences.

I understand we didn't follow the best practices. That we should have created a new branch to modify the history into it. Or that we should have remove parts of the code in the new branch `B` rather than in the original branch `A`.

But is there a way to tell git to change its merge strategy, so that it actually picks the differences in branch `B`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to change the merge strategy that way, because the history of the changes is relevant for the merging. It's not about just comparing two independent files, it's about applying changes.
Because `B` is an anchestor of `A`, after merging `A` all, of your changes on `B` *are* merged to master.

If a redundand merge of an older state would undo newer changes, the whole 
merging concept would become very ...weird.

What you actually want to do is not the *merging* of a change (because everything *is* merged) but the *reverting* of some changes that have already been merged.

To do so, you can use `git revert <sha>`, on your `master` branch, where by `<sha>` you can specify the commit that you want to revert.

`git revert <sha>` creates a new commit that does exactly the inversion of the specified commit.

**Original**

```
         master <- HEAD
           |
1----------5
 `-2--3--4´
      |  |
      B  A
```

**After `git revert 4`**

```
            master <- HEAD
              |
1----------5--6
 `-2--3--4´    `revert A
      |  |
      B  A
```

If you did more than one commit after `B`, you can specify a range:

```
git revert B..A
```

, which will create a separate revert commit for each original commit, or use

```
git revert --no-commit B..A
git commit -m"Revert everything at once"
```

to create one single revert commit for all reverted changes.